# Why does this CURL (shell/terminal) command fail to execute?

Tags: bash, shell, curl, terminal, command

Ok, I'm stumped on this one.  When I execute this CURL request, I get a response.  The response is the proxy is blocking it, but I do get a response...

```
curl http://1.2.3.4:8080/v1/digital/foundations/content/articles?presetList=dashboard \
    -H 'content-type: application/json' \
    -H 'countryCode: US' \
    -H 'uuid: 3456789' \
    -H 'client_id: 1234'
```

However, when I execute this CURL request--the only change being adding `-x ""` at the beginning--the CURL request doesn't execute.  I keep pressing return and terminal keeps adding new lines.  I have to press `CMD-C` to get out of it.

```
curl -x "" http://1.2.3.4:8080/v1/digital/foundations/content/articles?presetList=dashboard \
    -H 'content-type: application/json' \
    -H 'countryCode: US' \
    -H 'uuid: 3456789' \
    -H 'client_id: 1234'
```

Here's the result. See where the cursor is? It just keeps going down a line.

[image]

Tried this one too, but same thing...

```
curl --noproxy "*" \
    http://1.2.3.4:8080/v1/digital/foundations/content/articles?presetList=dashboard \
    -H 'content-type: application/json' \
    -H 'countryCode: US' \
    -H 'uuid: 3456789' \
    -H 'client_id: 1234'
```

So why the heck does the first one execute, but the second and third, where I'm trying to disable the proxy, does it simply sit there with me pressing return? I've seen it happen occasionally with other commands too, but I never know what's causing it.  Really frustrating.

Comment: Can you add `-v` option in `curl` and retry

Comment: The continuation character was a typo. (I was removing protected headers.) Fixing that now...

Comment: Aaaah... the `-v` helped.  Looks like it was executing, but not timing out and was actually running as it returned `*   Trying 1.2.3.4...
* TCP_NODELAY set`  That was it!  Mind putting that in an answer so I can mark it as such?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should add `-v` or `--verbose` option to your `curl` command to get detailed debugging information printed on your terminal to help you trace source of the problem.

As per `man curl`:

```
-v, --verbose
```

> Makes curl verbose during the operation. Useful for debugging and seeing **what's going on "under the hood"**. A line starting with `'>'`
>                 means "header data" sent by curl, `'<'` means "header data" received by curl that is hidden in normal cases, and a line starting with
>                 `'*'` means additional info provided by curl.

Comment: That was it.  It *was* executing.  It just wasn't able to reach the machine for some reason and was simply waiting.